What causes the lead conversion error: circular dependency in cross reference id?
Every time we convert a lead we get the error: circular dependency in cross reference id
I have tried the debug logs but they don't see the source of the error. This is new behavior for the last few days... Does anyone know what this is, or how to track it down? FWIW neither the contact nor the account is created, and linking to an existing account also fails. So in the simplest version, the converted lead is only creating a contact, not an account or opportunity.

this needs more information - what automations do you have on Account, Contact, Opportunity?  Have you looked at the debug log?

The debug log does not show any problems. I thought that was strange.

Check for lookup fields that point at the same record. Example: for an Account X, if Account.ParentId has the value of X.Id

I am aware of circular references. We can't convert ANY lead whether it creates an account or not. I have deactivated all relevant Triggers and Workflows and Flows.

Have you changed your Lead Mapping rules in any way that might cause this new behavior?

Checked everything i can think of there. Can you point me to an exact setup page that should be checked ?

Removed all lead mapping that didn't help.

any new managed packages get added recently?

We are having the same issue. It started on 10/14 after our upgrade to Winter '25. It only happens if the lead conversion must create a new account OR a new contact. If both of those records already exist, it will convert. I have not been able to figure out the issue. I have also tried removing all flows/validations/etc.

Thanks Terry we have filed a case with Salesforce Support and i will report back here. I was able to compare an older Sandbox with Production and can verify there are no permission issues or triggers, flows etc. that have changed.

Yes. We are a Salesforce partner and use the License Management Application that was recently upgraded. I was able to compare an older Sandbox with Production and can verify there are no suspicious permission issues or triggers, flows etc. that have changed.

I wanted to chime in that we encountered the same error today with no changes made. Not sure how to rectify this, I'm following in case anyone has a solution.

Started happening to us as well on October 21.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000ziEMF
Backend needs permission for Apex Lead Convert
Contact Support

Solved it for us as well.
